# Correlated random models of game trees

Tags: reference-request, gt.game-theory

Say we want to understand a game tree search algorithm in a theoretical context.  Thus, we want a parameterized family of problem instances, separate from actual games such as a chess, so that algorithms can be theoretically tested on small instances and then scaled up.

The simplest example would be a random tree (or random DAG) with random values at leaves chosen i.i.d. from some distribution.  Unfortunately, this model seems too simple to capture many interesting properties of game trees.  In particular, in a domain such as chess or go the values at leaves are both (1) highly correlated to nearby leaves and (2) highly correlated to simpler heuristics available at interior nodes.

A model that includes these correlations/heuristics would, for example, allow one to monitor the increasing strength of an agent as the depth of tree search increases.

**Question**: Are there papers which construct this kind of theoretical model of game trees with correlations between leaf values, or between leaf and heuristics at interior nodes?